# How many tests should I apply to test doubly Linked-list?

Tags: java, junit, doubly-linked-list

I have a doubly linked list `int`. I want to test `Get()` method:

```
public E get (int index)
```

how many tests should I implement in JUnit to Cover fully cases ?

Thank you and hope to have answer soon.

Comment: Use a coverage tool like jacoco, clover or cobertura, and you'll know if your tests cover all the code. It depends on your implementation. But by writing the code, you should know which corener cases/branches of the code you need to test. In fact, even the javadoc of the method should specify all the possible cases you need to test.

Comment: why do you have an index on your doubly linked list? doesn't that defeat the purpose? Re-indexing is O(n) usually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can follow all tests below:

1. Test `Get(0)`from an empty list.
2. Test `Get(-1)` from a list with 01 element
3. Test `Get(0)` from a list with 1 element
4. Test `Get(1)` from a list with 2 element.

Comment: Thank you, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is a bit broad, I think the following cases could be implemented.

1. accessing an empty list
2. accessing the first element of a nonempty list
3. accessing the last element of a nonempty list
4. accessing an element other than the first and the last of a list with at least 3 entries
5. accessing every element of a nonempty list

Comment: For test 1., check that `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown. Add test 6. accessing an element with negative index and 7. accessing an element with index greater than or equal to the list's size. They should also throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @Codor: why do I need to access an element with list at least 3 entries ? I think we can access the list with 2 entries is enough.

Comment: @MinhBui It was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Think of what  *behavior* the list should have.

For each sentence you can build with the pattern:
**given [data combination] as input the List should [expected behavior]**
you should have a *single test method*.

When building this sentences you should consider valid input data as well as error conditions.